# Casting from double always returns zero

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

Why does the following code returns zero, when compiled with clang?

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t square() {
    return ((uint32_t)((double)4294967296.0)) - 10;
}
```

The assembly it produces is:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

I would have expected that double to become zero (integer) and that minus would wrap it around. In other words, why doesn't in matter what number there is to subtract, as it always produces zero? Note that gcc does produce different numbers, as expected:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     eax, 4294967285
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

I assume casting 4294967296.0 to `uint32_t` is undefined behaviour but even then, I would expect to produce different results for different subtrahends.

Comment: `is undefined behaviour but even then, I would expect` - No. If something is undefined behavior, you don't expect. You can't expect. It is almost literally defined that way - if something is undefined behavior, you can't expect the code to do anything.

Comment: As an aside, the `(double)` “cast” *does nothing* here, since the literal is already of type `double`.

Comment: As undefined behavior is, well, undefined it would be great if a system behaved different each time it hits undefined behavior. That's what's supposed to happen on a [DS9k](https://enacademic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/2748465) - except, of course, that you can't rely on the behavior being different, either: if you tried to exploit that, a DS9k would foil your code.

Comment: Please specify whether you want a C answer or a C++ answer. Especially around casting and undefined behavior these languages differ quite much and should generally not be treated the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behaviour of casting an out-of-range `double` to an `unsigned` type is indeed *undefined*.

Wrap-around does **not** apply, even for an `unsigned` type.

This is an oft-forgotten rule.

Once program control reaches an undefined construct, the entire program is undefined, even somewhat paradoxically, statements that have already been ran.

Reference: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.fpint#1

Comment: May want to add a source: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.fpint#1

Answer (score 0):

g++ 5.4.0 gives 4294967285 (-11 unsigned), so it is up to the compiler what it wants to do with undefined behavior.

```
__Z6squarev:
LFB1023:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        movl    $-11, %eax
        movl    $0, %edx
        popl    %ebp
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```